# Angular Component Testing Injecting Generic Service

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, jasmine

I would like some help in setting up my Jasmine test so that I can use my generic Typescript service with my Angular component. The easiest way of explaining the problem is by showing you an example. I couldn't find any examples on the web addressing my exact problem.

I have a service like so:

```
MyGenericService<T extends MyParentInterface> {

    MyService(private serviceDependency: MyDependency){}

    doWork(obj: T){
        // do work
    }
}
```

I defined a factory like so:

```
export const myServiceFactory = (
    serviceDependency: MyDependency
) => {
    return new MyService<MyChildInterface>(serviceDependency);
};
```

I have a component like so:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [
        {
             provide: 'MyService',
             useFactory: myServiceFactory,
             deps: [ServiceDependency],
        },
    ]
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(@Inject('MyService') private readonly myService: MyService<MyChildInterface>){}
}
```

I can't set up the dependency injection correctly for my component test. It complains about the service dependency with the following error: `NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError ... Cannot find provider for ServiceDependency` . This is despite the fact that I have created a mocked factory. As follows:

```
const myServiceFactoryMock = () => {
    return new MyServiceMock<MyChildInterface>();
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: 'MyService',
                useFactory: myServiceFactoryMock
            },
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

---

I also tried defining the type using an InjectionToken like so:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService extends MyGenericService<MyChildInterface> {
    public static TOKEN = new InjectionToken<MyParentInterface>(
        'MyService_TOKEN'
    );
}
```

and in the shared module:

```
{
   provide: MyService.TOKEN,
   useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyService),
   multi: false,
},
```

and then injecting the service as follows:

```
@Inject(MyService.TOKEN) private myService: MyService,
```

Comment: In first case you need also to provide `ServiceDependency`.

Comment: Why is this still required if I have mocked the object? The mocked object does not have this dependency.

Comment: I actually avoided Angular dependency injection. I solved my problem of code duplication by using two abstract classes. One for the service and one for the component. The service injected both services - with one null. The abstract component was inherited by two components. The components injected the service that they required.

Comment: why you avoid Angular DI?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you properly mocked dependency but perhaps at wrong level as I've check it should be done in this way if provider is not a singleton but another instance from specific component:

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
  set: {
    providers: [
      {provide: 'MyService', useValue: {}} // Mock, spy - whatever you want
    ]
  }
});
```

Edit 1:
Here I found some useful information about `TestBed.overrideComponent` - https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios